# const discards qualifiers c++

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class "Fan" that have this function:

```
string getName();
```

and I wanna use it in another function outside the class:

```
string print(const Fan& fan) {
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "Fan : "  << fan.getName() ;

     return ss.str();
}
```

I get this error:

> ..\mtm_ex4.cpp:37:52: error: passing `'const mtm::Fan'` as 'this' argument of `'std::string mtm::Fan::getName()'` discards qualifiers `[-fpermissive]`

Why is that?!

---

**Update:**

And when I change it to:

```
string getName() const;
```

I get this error:

> undefined reference to `mtm::Fan::getName() const`

Comment: The function has to be `const` if you want to call it on a `const Fan`.

Comment: `getName()` is not `const`.

Comment: As a side note, I strongly encourage you (if "name" is an attribute of your fan), implemente getName in this way: const string& getName() const { return _name; }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to call a non-const member function on a const object.  Just change the function:

```
string getName() const;
```

I will say that that is not a very descriptive error message.

Edit: You need to add the `const` in *both* places, the declaration in the class and the definition in the source.

Comment: You need to change the definition too.

Comment: @user3036061, sorry I just assumed you'd know to change it in both places.

Comment: I wrote only the declaration until now so its not the problem

Comment: @user3036061 well that would explain it then, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter `fan` is a `const Fan&`, so you can only use it in ways that do not modify it. You need to tell the compiler that calling `getName` will not modify the object - it doesn't know this automatically. To do that, you simply write `const` after the argument list of `getName`:

```
string getName() const { ... };
```

Comment: now I get this error:
undefined reference to `mtm::Fan::getName() const'

Comment: @user3036061 Make sure you change both the declaration and the definition to have `const`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield What happened to your old name? :(

Comment: @0x499602D2 Decided to confuse everyone!

Comment: I wrote only the declaration until now so its not the problem

Comment: @user3036061 Well that's the problem then.... you can't call a function if it doesn't have a definition.